# Docker DCT for offline images

Tags: docker

We are planning to have DCT(Docker Content Trust) for offline images;  per documentation, this can be achieved by setting this flag: "allow-expired-cached-trust-data: true" but I am not sure where should I set this flag! can someone help? I am using Docker for Windows.

EDIT:
Here is my daemon.json:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "content-trust": {
    "allow-expired-cached-trust-data": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `~/.docker/trust`?

Comment: I still have this not working; also wondering what could have made someone to downvote this question? either that person knows something that I have not gone through or I have not put effort in getting there; it will be nice if that downvoter gives a clue so that I can pursue further.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the Docker Engine’s configuration file, which defaults to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

It's mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/content_trust/#using-dct-in-an-offline-environment).

> DCT is controlled by the Docker Engine’s configuration file. By default this is found at `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

Comment: does not work; "docker unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /run/config/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: allow-expired-cached-trust-data"